# Odd way of implementing the MD5 function in C#

Tags: c#, extension-methods, md5

I was looking for extension methods and stumbled in to a function that claims to mimic how PHP does the MD5 functions. Here's an exact copy(I don't get why the declaration and initialization of the Crypto were done separately...)

```
public static string MD5(this string s) {
    MD5CryptoServiceProvider provider;
    provider = new MD5CryptoServiceProvider();
    byte[] bytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(s);
    StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();

    bytes = provider.ComputeHash(bytes);

    foreach(byte b in bytes) {
        builder.Append(b.ToString("x2").ToLower());
    }

    return builder.ToString();
}
```

The MSDN library shows this as being the way to do it:

```
byte[] MD5hash (byte[] data) {
   // This is one implementation of the abstract class MD5.
   MD5 md5 = new MD5CryptoServiceProvider();

   byte[] result = md5.ComputeHash(data);

   return result;
}
```

Except for the argument being a string, what's the need for the stringbuilder and appending each byte? If I just do Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes on the string, I should have a byte array, usable for the method found in the MSDN library.

Can anyone point to a use for the extension method?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first method returns the hexadecimal encoding of the result. The latter returns it has a `byte[]` without encoding it as hex in a string.

The former is more of a convenience method when returning the result as a string (perhaps in a URL, form, etc).

Comment: +1 And the first method also takes a hex string as a parameter rather than a byte array.

Answer (score 0):

The whole stringbuilder thing is a way of converting the bytes into a hex string (e.g. convert 16 bytes into 32 chars). See [How do you convert Byte Array to Hexadecimal String, and vice versa?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/311165/how-do-you-convert-byte-array-to-hexadecimal-string-and-vice-versa-in-c) for a variety of other ways to accomplish the same thing.